# ICO Site Development, When should I transfer tokens to investors

Tags: erc-20, ico, presale

I am trying to develop ICO presale site and researched various ICO contracts on github.
I am now stuck because I can't know when I should transfer tokens to investors.
Someone wrote buyTokens functions as below.

[image]

And other person wrote buyTokens function as below.

[image]

As you can see, the former made logic that investors can get tokens instantly while the latter made logic that investors can claim their token after ICO finish.
I am not sure if investors would like without seeing tokens instantly on their wallet after clicking purchase button in the second case.
Can you please teach me how we can persuade investors wait until ICO finish to get their tokens?
I mean I want to know how ICO presale site can make guarantee for investors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are my options in ICOs, but most of projects prefer tokens to keep locked some time after the ICO, especially until the liquidity for the token is added, in order to make it tradeable on Uniswap, Pancakeswap, or whatever.

Comment: So, do you mean that I have to not transfer tokens while ICO and send tokens to investors on ClaimTokens invocation after ICO finish as the second image snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Most ICO projects have a timelock of at least 6 months or more.
In the meantime they prepare filling their liquidity pool with raised funds to give their tokens real value and make it tradeable on DEX (Pancakeswap, Uniswap, etc.).

Investors also prefer to see a timelock and vesting of tokens on these liquidity pools to avoid rugpulls or to prevent whales dumping the tokens, leaving others with breadcrumbs.